# Add (bind/join) multiple st_distance columns to sf object in R

Tags: r, sf, st-distance

I measured multiple distances between 2 `sf` objects using `st_distance` and I need to add these multiple distance columns to one of the previous `sf` objects. However, I'm not sure which is the best way, to add (bind/join/...) these columns...

Here my data: I use Country Polygons (NUTS0 from EUROSTAT) and subset German Neighbour Contries

```
library(giscoR)

nuts0 <-gisco_get_nuts(
  year = "2021",
  epsg = "3035",
  cache = TRUE,
  update_cache = FALSE,
  cache_dir = NULL,
  verbose = FALSE,
  resolution = "01",
  spatialtype = "RG",
  country = NULL,
  nuts_id = NULL,
  nuts_level = 0
)

Germany <- nuts0[nuts0$CNTR_CODE == "DE", ]
Neighbours <- st_touches(nuts0, nuts0)
DE_Neighbours <- nuts0[as.numeric(row.names(nuts0)) %in% Neighbours[[as.numeric(row.names(Germany))]], ]
```

And batches (> 1 million) of grided data from which I need to calculate the smallest distance from their middlepoints to german neighbour countries. Here a sample of my data, only with id and middlepoints:

```
id <- c("100mN30088E40461", "100mN30093E40449")
x <- c(4046150, 4044950)
y <- c(3008850, 3009350)
df <- data.frame(id,x,y)
Raster_points <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 3035)
```

Than I calculate the shortest distances to the borders and add the colnames:

```
Dist_Neighbours <- st_distance(Raster_points, DE_Neighbours)
colnames(Dist_Neighbours) <-  DE_Neighbours$CNTR_CODE
colnames(Dist_Neighbours) <- paste("distance", colnames(Dist_Neighbours), sep = "_")
```

So far it's fine. But how to append the distance columns to the `Raster_points` without losing the correct order? I tried these two ways:

Add each single column to sf object (which is not really satisfying):

```
Raster_points$CZ <- Dist_Neighbours[,"CZ"]
```

Or using bind_cols from dplyr:

```
NEW_sf <- Raster_points  %>% 
  bind_cols(Dist_Neighbours[,c(1:9)])
```

In both ways should be the order in the correct way as far as I tested, but I'm not fully sure. Is there a better way, maybe using a left join, mutate or something else?

Comment: Yes, output will be ordered, and there's no radically better way of putting two dataframes or matrices together; I'm not sure what you are trying to do, maybe `nngeo::st_nn()`which gives you the nearest neighbor distance (a single distance) would better suit your purposes.

Comment: Does plain old `cbind` not do what you want?

Comment: Your are right, cbind work as well. I thought maybe there is a better way, then a bind_cols/cbind without key field. Thanks, for your answers